# How to assess performance of an algorithm delivering solutions of varying quality?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

I lack formal knowledge about statistics and got lost in the Wikipedia articles about the subject.

I have an algorithm that produces a solution for a problem. There might be several solutions possible. Not all solutions are equally good, and I am able to give score for each solution.

I want to be able to tell if the algorithm is good or not.

For each problem I can calculate bounds on the best and worst possible solution (only bounds, not exact values).
I can also generate a random solutions for a problem, but not every random solution is a valid one (high chances for getting a valid one, though).

The data set I am going to use have problems of approximately the same difficulty.

Clearly I should use some statistical test, but which one? It seems that they require knowledge about the distribution and are more suitable for comparing algorithms.

**Edit:**

I do not want to add too much irrelevant specifics, so I will try to simplify.

I have an algorithm that solves a problem. for example, it finds a path between two nodes in a graph. The input is a graph. The output is a path.

Obviously, shorter paths are better than longer ones.

I want to know if my algorithm is good. I do not know exactly how to define "good", but that is where statistics can help me, is not it?

What I though about so far was to do the following:

1. Run the algorithm on a set of problems (problem is a graph). The sizes of all these  graphs are of the same order of magnitude.
2. Find a random path (in my specific problem it is possible to do) for each graph, and do this many times.
3. Compare the results of 1 and 2 to see if my algorithm is better than choosing a path at random.

Am I doing it right? How should I perform step 3?

Comment: I am having great difficulty following this. Can you describe the situation you are studying, the data you have, and the algorithms you are applying?

Comment: Are you interested in making some kind of inference about the distribution of solutions that you random solution generator produces?

Comment: @gung See my edit.

Comment: @jlovegren No. I want to compare the random solution generator to my algorithm and see if mine is better. Also, a-priory I know nothing about the distribution.

Comment: Your answer to @jlovegren suggests that hypothesis testing may not be what you really need. I suspect that your algorithm *is* better than random & that that can be shown, but that it's not very impressive or meaningful. I will edit to change the tag to machine-learning, as I bet some of those folks will be able to help you.

Comment: If by "better", you mean that the mean path length of your algorithm is less than the mean path length of the random solutions, then you might just run a largish number of iterations then use a t-test. http://www.statmethods.net/stats/ttest.html

Answer (score 1):

[The problem of finding shortest paths on graphs is well-studied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal).

I don't think it's too important to know whether or not your method is better than **random** because there are a number of well-studied algorithms that solve (some specific) graph traversal problems quite well.

I think the more relevant comparison is to ask wether your method is *better* (1) for some special graph, such as a planar or chromatic graph or (2) for graphs of a certain size or density or number of edges. Note that *better* can mean any number of things: lower working memory requirements, lower computational complexity, better worst-case behavior, better average behavior.